# mongoose aggregate match not working with regex

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need to find some records using regex. When the parameter value ends in 0 the result is empty, but when the last character is different from zero (1 - 9) the query works fine.

```
Invoice.aggregate([{
  '$lookup': {
    'from': 'clients',
    'localField': 'client',
    'foreignField': '_id',
    'as': 'client'
  }
}, {
  '$unwind': '$client'
}, {
  '$lookup': {
    'from': 'employees',
    'localField': 'sold_by',
    'foreignField': '_id',
    'as': 'sold_by'
  }
}, {
  '$unwind': '$sold_by'
}, {
  '$lookup': {
    'from': 'payment_types',
    'localField': 'payment_type',
    'foreignField': '_id',
    'as': 'payment_type'
  }
}, {
  '$unwind': '$payment_type'
}, {
  '$lookup': {
    'from': 'payments',
    'localField': 'payments.payment',
    'foreignField': '_id',
    'as': 'payment'
  }
}, {
  '$unwind': '$payment'
}, {
  $match: {
        'invoice': {
      $regex: /2490/i
    }
  }
}])
```

When the query works the result exclude all the records that ends in 0.
I try using the regex in this other way

```
"$match" : {
                "invoice" : /^.*2490.*$/i
            }
```

and the result is the same.

I use regex in other String fields and work fine only in this field doesn't work. the field store values like this

```
{
'000-0000-2490',
'000-0000-2491',
'000-0000-2492'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually **`-`** is a special character and will not work with the `regular expression` syntax.

Instead you need to use  [**`$regex`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) operator here

```
{ "$match" : { "invoice" : { "$regex": "000-0000-2490", "$options": "i" } } }
```

Comment: Does not work. Same result. When the I pass values with the last character equal 0 the result is empty