# MongoDB count documents that match with regex

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I want to count documents that match with regex.

```
[
  {
    fullName: "Vehicle 1",
    tags: [
        "car",
        "bike"
    ],
  },
  {
    fullName: "Vehicle 1",
    tags: [
        "car"
    ],
  },
  {
    fullName: "Vehicle 1",
    tags: [
        "unknown"
    ],
  }
]
```

Expected Output

```
[
  {
    name: "car",
    count: 2
  },
  {
    name: "bike",
    count: 1
  },
  {
    name: "unknown",
    count: 1
  },
]
```

What I tried so far

```
model.aggregate([
        { $unwind: '$tags' },
        {
          $match: {
            tags: new RegExp(text, 'i'),
          },
        },
        { $group: { _id: '$tags', count: { $sum: 1 } } },
        { $project: { name: '$_id', _id: false, count: '$count' } },
      ])
```

It returns error; Type 'RegExp' is not assignable to type 'Expression' error.

Also I tried,

```
model.aggregate([
        { $unwind: '$tags' },
        {
          $match: {
            tags: { $regex: new RegExp(text), $options: 'i' },
          },
        },
        { $group: { _id: '$tags', count: { $sum: 1 } } },
        { $project: { name: '$_id', _id: false, count: '$count' } },
      ])
```

I returns error; Object literal may only specify known properties, and '$regex' does not exist in type 'ArrayElemAt | First | Last | Reduce | ObjectToArray | RegexFindAll ... 132 more

mongoose version "^6.4.0",

@nestjs/mongoose version "^9.1.0"

Related questions

[mongoose aggregate match not working with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51832874/mongoose-aggregate-match-not-working-with-regex)

[How to use $regex in mongodb aggregation query within $match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252208/how-to-use-regex-in-mongodb-aggregation-query-within-match)

Answer (score 0):

use this way :

```
model.aggregate([
        { $unwind: '$tags' },
        {
          $match: {
            tags: { $regex: text , $options: 'i' },
          },
        },
        { $group: { _id: '$tags', count: { $sum: 1 } } },
        { $project: { name: '$_id', _id: false, count: '$count' } },
      ]);
```

tested on : https://mongoplayground.net/p/h8Q1nn02Iuj

Comment: same error; Object literal may only specify known properties, and '$regex' does not exist in type 'ArrayElemAt | First | Last | Reduce | ObjectToArray | RegexFindAll | Split | SetDifference

Comment: Yeah, It's working. Also, I checked with mongoDB shell. Problem is about the mongoose, there is no regex type definition for $match.